# Setting an specific format for an Excel Column with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working with a macro that gathers data (code identifier) from a source with a print screen and pastes it to excel.

Problem is, every time a data point (identifier) is a value with an "E" included, excel interprets as a scientific notation and changes the original value.

Is there a way to make excel set the column in which I have those values to text before pasting, or for it to paste the whole content as text automatically?

Comment: `Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns(3).NumberFormat="@"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this set a specific column range to text?

Comment: @cyboashu's comment will set the third column in the UsedRange. You can also write `Sheet1.Columns("C:C")` or any `.Columns("E:E")` to change a specific column no matter the `UsedRange`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options presented in the comments work to set a column type:

```
Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns(3).NumberFormat="0.00"
```

However the option that worked best in this application was:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

As UsedRange was not the preferred reference used in this project.